# Execute Terraform upon resource creation failure

Tags: terraform

I was wondering if the community could help. Essentially I am trying to execute a terraform file and would like it to proceed if a certain resource block fails to execute. I have tried using timeout but that just kills the entire process one the time out is reached.

The broader issue is I am trying to terminate an instance and trying to ssh first before termination. What I would like is if ssh time_out is reached proceed to destroy as opposed to stopping the destroy process if it cannot ssh within the time frame.
Here is what I am using:

```
 connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    user     = "root"
    password = "${var.root_password}"
    host     = "${var.host}"
    timeout = "10s"
    }
```

Comment: Well, you can run `terraform apply` again.

Comment: It would still fail once it get's to the time_out. Essentially I need it to time out and continue running the rest of the terraform code. The broader issue is I am trying to terminate an instance and trying to ssh first before termination. What I would like is if ssh time_out is reached proceed to destroy as opposed to stopping the destroy process if it cannot ssh within the time frame

Comment: But why set it to 10 seconds only then?

Comment: I'm trying to ssh to see if its running, if after 10s no connection then the instance might be stopped. If it's stopped the ssh shouldn't work but terraform should still destroy the instance.

Comment: Wait, you want to destroy the instance? Also, there is no other way to continue applying changes if one of the steps fails, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah this issue is for when you run terraform destroy. I am trying to execute some commands. Hence it would attempt to ssh and then run those commands. What I would like is if the ssh doesn't work, it should continue to execute the destroy process.